# my average method keeps returning a rounded int value instead of double

Tags: java

I'm writing a program for an introduction to Java class and I have to write my own method,  but it keeps returning  as a rounded int.  So an average of 74.6 will return as 74.0. here is the method.

```
static double average(ArrayList<Integer> user1){
  int sum = 0;
  double mean2 = 0.0;
  for(int i = 0; i < user1.size(); i++){
    sum = sum + user1.get(i);
  }
  mean2 = sum / user1.size();
  return mean2;
}
```

I know that the problem is on line 7 but I don't know why.

Comment: `user1.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).average().orElseGet(()->.0);`

Comment: An int / int is an int. If you want a double you must cast it before calculating.

Answer (score 2):

You're dividing an integer by an integer because you are dividing by an ArrayList size, which is an integer, thus yielding a whole number. What you need to do is either change `sum`'s data type or cast:

```
double sum = 0;
```

Or,

```
(double) sum / user1.size();
```

Now what this does is achieve double division yielding a double result.

Answer (score 1):

change the data type of variable sum from int to double. Here sum and user.size both are integer so result would be also a integer. If you will change the sum to double the result would be double type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast to double before you divide like so

```
mean2 = (double)sum / user1.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Division if int with int in java will result in type of integer as here your sum is also integer and size of list is also integer so your result will be int, code with required changes is below

```
static double average(ArrayList<Integer> user1){
          int sum = 0;
          double mean2 = 0.0;
          int userSize=user1.size();
          for(int i = 0; i < userSize; i++){
            sum = sum + user1.get(i);
          }
          mean2 = (double)sum / userSize;
          return mean2;
        }
```

OR

```
static double average(ArrayList<Integer> user1){
          double  sum = 0;
          double mean2 = 0.0;
          int userSize=user1.size();
          for(int i = 0; i < userSize; i++){
            sum = sum + user1.get(i);
          }
          mean2 = sum / userSize;
          return mean2;
        }
```